# How to filter meta_values using REST API

Tags: filters, rest-api, meta-value

i am able to get the data by make an API called with these args `?meta_key=frequent&meta_value=day`

are there any possible way to filter with multiple `meta_value`? i already tried `meta_value=day,week` but it retured me empty array.

Comment: There's no method to filter by meta values in the core REST API. You would need to use `rest_post_query` to filter the query and support custom arguments.